# How to prevent children click on parent click

Tags: jquery, click

I have done the following code structure and doing `addClass item_box_popup` and `removeClass item_box` on click of `item_box div`.

```
<div class="item_box"> <!--This is the small div which when clicked changes to the item_box_popup div-->
  <div class="name">...</div>
  <div class="detail">...</div>
</div>

<div class="item_box_popup"> <!--This div expands to show the detail and the children in it has a click event-->
  <div class="name">...</div>
  <div class="detail">...</div>
</div>
```

The `item_box div` has a click event in it and not the children. The working is to change the div to `item_box_pop div` by `addClass` and `removeClass` when clicked.

The `item_box_popup` does not have a click event but the children has the click event defined. We have used `delegate` to define the click event for `.item_box_popup .name` etc.

The problem is when we click the `item_box div` the click event defined for `.item_box_popup .name` is also getting triggered. This may be due to the change class defined on click for `.item_box`.

I don't want the click event to trigger on the children when `.item_box` is clicked. I have tried `undelegate` to stop triggering of click on item_box children and just do the change class defined in the click for it but this is not working.

The click event for `.item_box`

```
$('.slide > div').bind('click',function(e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('item_box_popup')){
        var index=$('.slide > div').index(this);
            $(this).removeClass('item_box');
            $(this).addClass('item_box_popup');     
        Nomad.config.firstVisibleItem=index;<!--This is to set the position for .item_box_popup-->              
    }           
});
```

The click event for `.item_box_popup`

```
$("body").delegate('.item_box_popup .name, .item_box_popup .detail','click', function(e){
  //working code here for this
});
```

`e.stopPropagation();` disables the default click handler of `.item_box`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding event.preventDefault(); after the call that you do want to happen, it stops the default action from happening e.g. the default action of an a element.

I can't say exactly where to try the call or whether it will solve your problem without seeing your js code though. The html isn't where your problem is, its the js code, so if this (or the other answer that posted while I was typing this!) doesn't work can you edit your post to include your js, please?

**Update:**

I've copied your code into JSFiddle and added an e.stopPropagation() call to the item_box click handler, and it works as I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/chkaQ/2/

When you click on an item_box child div, it changes it to an item_box_popup and doesn't execute the item_box_popup child click event... have I got it wrong, or is that not what you want it to do?

Comment: Can you post your js code? Its very difficult to debug without knowing what you are debugging :-)

Comment: @FluttyKitten I have posted my click event which is conflicting. I hope you will now have an idea of my problem

Comment: @FlufftKitten Thanks FlufftKitten this solves my problem. You have got the problem right. Actually i was using the stopPropagation(); event in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6):

You need to prevent the event from 'bubbling' up to the parent using stopPropagation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: On click the class is changed immediately for which the event.stopPropagation is not working.

Comment: the children of the div with the click event all need stopPropagation()

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but this prevents the default click function of `.item_box`